# Why does merging two DataFrames by a common column yield an empty result?

Tags: python, pandas

I am processing two DataFrame objects with data from a survey and I cannot merge them correctly. The structures look like this:

```
In [93]: numeric_answers
Out[93]: 
   ANSWER_COUNT RESPONSE
1            50        1
2            21        2
4             3        4


In [94]: readable_values
Out[94]: 
                                                    MEANING
RESPONSE                                                   
 1                                                     male
 2                                                   female
 3                                              transgender
 5        non-binary, genderqueer, or gender non-conforming
 6                    a different identity (please specify)
 4                                   prefer not to disclose
-9                                             Not answered
```

My objective is to:

- merge them using the `RESPONSE` column
- resulting in a DataFrame with the columns `['RESPONSE', 'MEANING', 'ANSWER_COUNT']`
- with absent values set to `N/A` (though 0 would work too)

An example of desired output:

```
RESPONSE                                        MEANING  ANSWER_COUNT
   1                                               male           50
   2                                             female           21
   3                                        transgender           NaN
   5  non-binary, genderqueer, or gender non-conforming           NaN
   6              a different identity (please specify)           NaN
   4                             prefer not to disclose           3
  -9                                       Not answered           NaN
```

Having read the documentation for `merge` I conclued that what I need is `pd.merge(readable_values, numeric_answers)`, but this operation produces an empty result:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [RESPONSE, MEANING, ANSWER_COUNT]
Index: []
```

Having experimented with various arguments I got a somewhat promising result with `merge(readable_values, numeric_answers, on='RESPONSE', how='outer')`:

```
(Pdb) pd.merge(readable_values, numeric_answers, on='RESPONSE', how='outer')
   RESPONSE                                            MEANING  ANSWER_COUNT
0       1.0                                               male           NaN
1       2.0                                             female           NaN
2       3.0                                        transgender           NaN
3       5.0  non-binary, genderqueer, or gender non-conforming           NaN
4       6.0              a different identity (please specify)           NaN
5       4.0                             prefer not to disclose           NaN
6      -9.0                                       Not answered           NaN
7       1.0                                                NaN          50.0
8       2.0                                                NaN          21.0
9       4.0                                                NaN           3.0
```

However, it merges by appending values, whereas I need it to *intersect* the entries using the `RESPONSE` column. What is the ideologically recommended way to achieve this with Pandas?

Comment: make sure that `RESPONSE` column has the same dtype in both DFs

Comment: @MaxU, there is indeed a difference, `readable_values['RESPONSE']` is `int64`, while `numeric_answers['RESPONSE']` is of type `object`. However, at this point I am confused, because an answer below implies that data types are not relevant in this context.

Comment: the dtype IS relevant. Make sure that you have the same dtype and try again Andy's solution...

Comment: Indeed, after converting the types, I got the desired result, thanks! For future archeologists, here's what I did `numeric_answers['RESPONSE'] = numeric_answers['RESPONSE'].apply(pd.to_numeric)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`readable_values` has RESPONSE as the index, rather than as a column.
You can do the merge as:

```
In [11]: numeric_answers.merge(readable_values, left_on='RESPONSE', right_index=True, how='outer')
Out[11]:
   ANSWER_COUNT  RESPONSE                                            MEANING
1          50.0         1                                               male
2          21.0         2                                             female
4           3.0         4                             prefer not to disclose
4           NaN         3                                        transgender
4           NaN         5  non-binary, genderqueer, or gender non-conforming
4           NaN         6              a different identity (please specify)
4           NaN        -9                                       Not answered
```

an alternative is to `reset_index` of `readable_values` first:

```
In [12]: numeric_answers.merge(readable_values.reset_index(), on='RESPONSE', how='outer')
Out[12]:
   ANSWER_COUNT  RESPONSE                                            MEANING
0          50.0         1                                               male
1          21.0         2                                             female
2           3.0         4                             prefer not to disclose
3           NaN         3                                        transgender
4           NaN         5  non-binary, genderqueer, or gender non-conforming
5           NaN         6              a different identity (please specify)
6           NaN        -9                                       Not answered
```

---

Note the distinction which you can see in how they're rendered:

```
In [21]: readable_values
Out[21]:
                                                    MEANING
RESPONSE
 1                                                     male
 2                                                   female
 3                                              transgender
 5        non-binary, genderqueer, or gender non-conforming
 6                    a different identity (please specify)
 4                                   prefer not to disclose
-9                                             Not answered

In [22]: readable_values.reset_index()  # RESPONSE is now a column
Out[22]:
   RESPONSE                                            MEANING
0         1                                               male
1         2                                             female
2         3                                        transgender
3         5  non-binary, genderqueer, or gender non-conforming
4         6              a different identity (please specify)
5         4                             prefer not to disclose
6        -9                                       Not answered
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer. Although everything you say makes sense, executing the same functions yields different results on my machine (same as before), so I suspect there must be some subtle difference somewhere. Here is a replication of your suggestions, but not the same results http://pastebin.com/raw/mRD1XuXN